# MYSQL. SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS and FOUND_ROWS() are not working correct

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I am having an issue with MYSQL. SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS and FOUND_ROWS() are not working correct.

Issue:

- first time the total returns 1
- second time the total returns the correct
  number 3,500

MYSQL version:

mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.10, for osx10.9 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

I am trying to return a list from tables and another column in that list will be repeated for each row. (containing the total rows for the select).

This way I can get all the data and total rows in one select...

Select is below.

```
    SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM 
      (SELECT A.MEMBER_ID, A.USERNAME, B.ZIP, B.INTERESTS, C.ADDRESS   
       FROM MEMBER A,  DATA B, ADDRESS C        
       WHERE A.GENDER = "F" 
       AND A.MEMBER_ID = B.MEMBER_ID   
       AND A.MEMBER_ID = C.MEMBER_ID  
       AND UPPER (A.CANCEL_FLAG) = "N"      
       ORDER BY A.LAST_LOGIN_DATE DESC ) res,    
    (select FOUND_ROWS() as "total_result"  from dual ) tot    
    Limit 1, 15
```

Comment: 1.) Is the ORDER BY correct at the inner SELECT or should the the closing ")" before the ORDER BY?   
2.) Do you have a bit more info about table type and structure?

Comment: why would it need a closing ")" before the ORDER BY? 2.)  ?? Tables are basic tables. I do not think there is anything special about them. I am just trying to return a list from the table and another column that will be repeated for each row.. containing the total rows... This way I can get all the data and total rows in one select...

Comment: `select FOUND_ROWS()` tells you the number of rows found by the last select, not the current one. So what you are seeing is the expected outcome.

Comment: ok.. then how do I get the found_rows() with my current select? I have just migrated from Oracle and it used to work fine. I would like to have my data and row count in one select.

Comment: Ok got the point, you would like to have the Result of SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS in the same Result as your data, and to you like'd have the "total_result" in every row. 
Not sure if this is possible with MySQL. We always use two different Querys. You could try something with "UNION" to but that bring the "total_result" in a result row, not a column.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make this work in mysql, you can do a subquery using `COUNT`. You might be able to make it simpler by only counting the `MEMBER` table, if you can assume that the `MEMBER_ID` always exists in `DATA` and `ADDRESS`.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT A.MEMBER_ID, A.USERNAME, B.ZIP, B.INTERESTS, C.ADDRESS   
        FROM MEMBER A,  DATA B, ADDRESS C        
        WHERE A.GENDER = "F" 
            AND A.MEMBER_ID = B.MEMBER_ID   
            AND A.MEMBER_ID = C.MEMBER_ID  
            AND UPPER (A.CANCEL_FLAG) = "N"      
        ORDER BY A.LAST_LOGIN_DATE DESC
) res, (
    SELECT COUNT(*) as "total_result" 
        FROM MEMBER A 
            JOIN DATA B ON A.MEMBER_ID = B.MEMBER_ID 
            JOIN ADDRESS C ON A.MEMBER_ID = C.MEMBER_ID 
        WHERE A.GENDER='F'
) tot    
LIMIT 1, 15
```

See https://www.percona.com/blog/2007/08/28/to-sql_calc_found_rows-or-not-to-sql_calc_found_rows/ for a discussion about whether this is terrible or not.

Comment: That should work, but to double up the whole query, just to get the total result, looks not god for me. I would prefer different querys. One with "SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS" and LIMIT and a second one with "FOUND_ROWS()"

Comment: Right - see the link for a discussion about which of those is more efficient. In practice, it seems that the "obvious" answer isn't necessarily right.

Comment: know about the link and reseach of percona, but the the SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS looks a bit straighter and in practice you should have a look, how much performane you gain with "COUNT(*)".

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I figured it out..

I am using a stored procedure.

I just did a second select. 
  select FOUND_ROWS() as 'total_result'  from dual;

This returned the correct value.

Thanks
Phil

Comment: this works but does now work with order by. I am using MySql and SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS. It seems to be disabling the order by clause.

MySql Server version: 5.7.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (Ubuntu)

SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM (

disables the ORDER BY clause